# reverse tethering : share laptop internet connection thru bluetooth

Tags: reverse-tether

im rooted, nexus 5

I work in the middle of the bush, no cell coverage.  **NO ROUTERS ALLOWED**.

I would like to share my laptop's wired internet connection.  Either create a ****hidden wifi*** hotspot **that no one will be able to detect*** or share my laptops internet thru Bluetooth

could someone pleaaaase help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install Toshiba Bluetooth stack (don't forget to reboot)
2. Right click Toshiba Bluetooth icon in the system tray and choose "Option"
3. Turn on "PAN" service and "DHCP" option.
4. Open terminal (Press Win+R, then entering cmd). Go to the Toshiba installation folder (similar to this):

   `cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack"`

   And rerun the PAN service by entering:

   `TosBtPSS.exe /END`

   `TosBtPSS.exe /NAP`

Then you can share the internet by using ICS, Bridge Network or 3rd party NAT in Windows such as NAT32.

I also wrote a [Bluetooth reverse tethering tutorial](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=36868&page=1&extra=#pid701148).

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:**

- Rooted Android device with "USB tethering" capability.
- Windows PC with a working Internet connection.
- USB cable to connect your Android to your PC.
- Terminal Emulator on your Android. If you don't want to type
  commands on your touchscreen with Terminal Emulator, you can use
  your PC keyboard to enter commands with `adb shell`. adb is a part
  of Android SDK which is available for download from Google. To use
  adb, you need to enable "USB debugging" on your Android.
- Optional, BusyBox on your Android.

**Step 1**:

- Connect your Android to PC by USB cable and enable `USB tethering`
- Windows will automatically search Windows Update and install driver
  for you. You can skip Windows Update search and install manually an
  already included driver from Microsoft.
- In Install Driver window, click `Browse My Computer, then Let me
  pick...`, select `Network Adapters`, uncheck `Show Compatible
  Hardware`, look at `Microsoft Corporation` at the left column
- Choose `Remote NDIS Compatible Device` from the right column. You can
  also install or update a driver from Device Manager in Windows.

**Step 2:**

- Open `Network Connections` in `Control Panel`. Right click on an
  Internet connection that you have.
- select `Properties`. In tab `Sharing` (or `Advanced` for Windows XP),
  click `Allow other network users to connect through...`, then select
  the USB connection in dropdown list below. Click OK.
- Windows will automatically setup your USB network connection and
  assign to it an IP address, default for Windows 7: `192.168.137.1`,
  default for Windows XP: `192.168.0.1`.
- You can see your Internet connection is now "Shared" and your USB
  connection is now `Unidentified network`. Your PC setup is now done!

**Step 3:**
Open Terminal Emulator on your Android. Type:

```
su

netcfg rndis0 dhcp
```

(The name for usb interface inside Android may vary. It is usually rndis0 or usb0. Type `busybox ifconfig`to identify the name.

**When automatical dhcp method does not work.**

Type:

```
 ifconfig rndis0 192.168.137.2 (192.168.0.2 for Windows XP) netmask 255.255.255.0

 route add default gw 192.168.137.1 (192.168.0.1 for Windows XP) dev rndis0
```

**If route fails, try:**

```
busybox route add default gw 192.168.137.1 (192.168.0.1 for Windows XP) dev rndis0 dev rndis0
```

**Some applications (download in Google Play, GMail, Facebook...) don't recognize Internet connection. You can try this way**

Enable temporarily 3G connection on your Android and type

```
ifconfig rmnet0 0.0.0.0
```

(The name for 3G interface inside Android may vary: `ppp0`, `rmnet0`... Type `busybox ifconfig` to identify name)

**Source:** http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494