# Reverse tethering via Bluetooth: How to share PC internet connectivity with android phone via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, reverse-tether

OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64

Phone: Galaxy Ace 3 - android 4.2 (rooted)

I'm aware of normal tethering scenarios in which the user can share the Mobile Data connection with other phones/pcs via wifi-hotspot, bluetooth tethering or USB tethering and my phone is capable of all of them.

Let's assume my laptop is connected to the internet via lan and I want to share the internet with my phone via bluetooth(not wifi or usb). I think it's called reverse tethering.

Is there any way to accomplish this? (It seems Mac is capable of doing that: [How to share your internet connection over Bluetooth](https://kiskeyix.org/articles/552))

by the way:

->this method is not working(using ICS): [How to Share the Internet With Bluetooth](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/share-internet-bluetooth-58494.html)

->BlueDUN app is for sharing mobile data/wifi connectivity of the phone with another phone/pc

->Toshiba Bluetooth Stack is not working

**Update:**
On the Linux front there's an application called 'blueman' that does this

Comment: Why not do your reverse tethering over USB?  Alternatively, why not buy a wireless router?

Comment: it's not matter of other options, it's about knowing the possibility of such a scenario

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I like to think that there are many hypothetical situations this would be beneficial for. An example would be if you're away from home using a wired only connection, but your PC has a Bluetooth adapter handy.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question which myself  couldn't get a satisfactory solution. This solution posted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/81138/209414) seemed promising although I found out the bluetooth stack supports fewer bluetooth adapters and also some link was taken down.

Having said that, since you are running Windows, Microsoft seems to have at least provided a solution to that issue, but it supports newer editions of Windows (should be Creators update IIRC):

> - Open the Settings app either by clicking its icon on the left side of the Start menu or simultaneously pressing the Windows logo + R
>   keys.
> - In the Settings app, go to Network & Internet  > Mobile Hotspot page.
> - To turn on mobile hotspot, turn on the option labelled Share my Internet connection with other devices.
> - Under share my connection over, choose bluetooth option.

Simply pair the two and enjoy the connection

[image]

<sup>*Credits (and photo) [Mobile hotspot or Wi-Fi hotspot in Windows 10](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-mobile-hotspot-in-windows-10-easy-way/)*</sup>

<sup>Windows feature are most buggy for me, that's why I prefer to try other workarounds first.</sup>

**Edit**

I noticed that the default bluetooth stack (Microsoft) doesn't support ICS as shown in this [discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/win10-bluetooth-pan/71b0f1ed-510d-45a4-9550-4e92100e879c), with support having been dropped since Windows Vista era.

However a probable workaround is using alternative proprietary software like [BlueSoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/), which make make the PC act as bluetooth access point as dicussed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1064209).